# YoutubePlayer with ViewPager in PagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-youtube-api

I am loading Youtube video in Viewpager but if there are two videos in the view pager only second video is able to play. Please help 
I want to load all the videos in the view pager if there is more than one video only last video is able to play.

YoutubeVideo Loader Class :-

```
public class YoutubePlayerControl implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
private Context mContext;
private String youtubeVideoId;

public YoutubePlayerControl(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

public void playVideo(YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView, String videoId) {
    this.youtubeVideoId = videoId;
    youTubePlayerView.initialize(Config.KEY_YOUTUBE, this);
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
    if (!b) {
        youTubePlayer.cueVideo(youtubeVideoId);
    }
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

}
```

}

here is  Adapter Class : -

```
public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private List<FeedMetaData> feedMetaDatas;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private YoutubePlayerControl youtubePlayerControl;

public MyViewPagerAdapter(Context mContext, List<FeedMetaData> feedMetaDatas) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.feedMetaDatas = feedMetaDatas;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.mContext);
    youtubePlayerControl = new YoutubePlayerControl(this.mContext);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return feedMetaDatas.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view.equals(object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.nojoto_series_viewpager_row, container, false);

    YouTubePlayerView youtubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);

    FeedMetaData feedMetaData = feedMetaDatas.get(position);
    //playing Youtube Video 
   youtubePlayerControl.playVideo(playerFragment, feedMetaData.getVideoId());

    container.addView(itemView);
    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
}

@Override
public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

your `YoutubePlayerControl` class have to extend `YouTubeBaseActivity` class. otherwise it will crash

Comment: MainActivity extend YouTubeBaseActivity and YoutubePlayerControl is used to control the play option Only.